# Build Boost Coroutine2

Tags: c++, boost

*As this has been marked as duplicate earlier: This problem has nothing to do with the basic "How to install boost...". Boost is installed and all libraries but coroutine2 are working correctly. So this is a coroutine2 problem.*

When trying to compile my project I get the following linker error:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_coroutine2-vc140-mt-gd-1_64.lib'
```

After checking I noticed that file was missing, even though I built boost with the following command:

```
b2 install --build-type=complete msvc -mt
```

So I tried to build it manually using the following command:

```
b2 install --build-type=complete msvc -mt --with-coroutine2
```

Something interesting happened: It built Boost.Context (which was already built by the first command) which it is built on, but no Coroutine2 lib in sight.

Now I tried to run the project on my other computer with boost 1.61 installed - and it worked flawlessly! After checking the coroutine2/detail/config.hpp (which determines which library to link against) I noticed that boost 1.61 wants to load the coroutine lib while boost 1.64 requires a coroutine2 lib...

On Boosts [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) page Coroutine2 isn't listed as a "has-to-be-built" library and after dissecting the config.hpp file I came up with the idea to define `#define BOOST_COROUTINES2_NO_LIB` which resulted in many unknown symbols...

I don't know what else I can do, please help, dear professionals :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I've found which exact cpp is generating LNK1104 error. Then I've enabled "Preprocess to a File" option to see in the preprocessed file, who's making the linking request. Then bingo!

```
#line 401 "C:\\libdev4\\boost\\boost/config/auto_link.hpp"
#pragma comment(lib,  "boost_coroutine2" "-" "vc140" "-mt" "-gd" "-" "1_64" ".lib")
```

So, it's a bug in boost 1.64 auto_link.hpp

p.s. disabling the automatic linking via defining BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB in my project and setting the necessary libs manually, solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

boost.coroutine2 is a header-only library - a libboost_coroutine2-vc140-mt-gd-1_64.lib ist not created. You should check the linker flags of your project and remove the reference to libboost_coroutine2.

EDIT: remove sub directory 'build' from boost.coroutine2

Comment: there are no linker flags and no reference to libboost_coroutine2. the exactly same project compiles on another PC with boost 1.61 installed. Is it possible that during boosts build process there are some flags set which cause the trouble? 

When I check the input libraries in the linker tab (MSVC) there is clearly not a single boost lib. All the linking happens via boosts auto linking (I assume)

Comment: I would try a newer version of boost - I remember earlier versions of boost.coroutien2 have had a bug in the Jamfile (Makefile equivalent).

Comment: Unfortunately 1.64 is the newest version. The older version 1.61 works flawlessly!

Comment: @mattideluxe: as I told you - boost.coroutine2 is a header-only library - you won't get a library (shared-objects) generated for boost.coroutine2. You have to convince your build env that you don't need libboost_coroutine2-vc140-mt-gd-1_64.lib.

Comment: What can I do but '#define BOOST_COROUTINES2_NO_LIB'? This makes it not use the lib but results in unknown symbols errors.

Comment: @mattideluxe: in your project you have to remove libboost_coroutine2 from the linker flags

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in Boost 1.64 when building from MS Visual Studio.
With Boost 1.65 I don't face this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy  the `libboost_coroutine-xxx.lib` to `boost_coroutine2-xxx.lib` and put it in the lib path. because `oroutine2` no use lib. So no matter what content in the lib make no difference .